# C++ private variable in struct being modified without using mutator func, not sure why? - OpenGL particle system

Tags: c++

I am using OpenGL to write my first particle system and am stuck with an error I can't reason about. My particle struct's "active" property is private (while trying to debug this issue), and I have accessor/mutator funcs for active that print to console when used (again for debugging).

I instantiate active=false in constructor in particle struct. In the main() method, I print the values of "active" for each particle, and they are all set to true, even though it appears nothing has called the mutator method.

I only call mutator methods in functions that are called by the glutIdleFunc() callback function, which isn't even set until after the code in main() that prints the particle.active values.

Here is some code if it gives insight:

```
struct RainDrop {
  private:
    bool active;

  public:
    glm::vec3 position, velocity, color;
    float     life;

    RainDrop(): 
      position(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), 
      velocity(0.0f), 
      color(1.0f), 
      life(0.0f),
      active(false)
      { }
    
    void setActive(bool b, std::string caller) {
      active = b;
    }

    bool getActive() {
      return active;
    }
};

struct Rain {
  std::vector<RainDrop*> drops;

  Rain() {
    drops = std::vector<RainDrop*>();

    RainDrop drop;
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_RAIN_DROPS; i++) {
      drop = RainDrop();
      drops.push_back(&drop);
    }
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  viewer.position.x = 400;
  ... more viewer setting

  // Add all rain to inactive stack
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < NUM_RAIN_DROPS; i++) {
    inactiveRain.push(rain.drops[i]);
  }

  srand(time(NULL));
  initGraphics(argc, argv);   
  glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
  glutIdleFunc(stepRain);
  glutMainLoop();             
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
  Rain() {
    drops = std::vector<RainDrop*>();

    RainDrop drop;
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_RAIN_DROPS; i++) {
      drop = RainDrop();
      drops.push_back(&drop);
    }
  }
```

You assign a `RainDrop` to the local variable `drop` and then store the adress of that local variable in the member vector. Once this constructor returns the local `drop` is gone. Its lifetime ended. The pointer in the vector is invalid. Dereferencing it later invokes undefined behavior.

Most likely you want to use a `std::vector<RainDrop> drops;` instead. Raw pointers are to be avoided and if there is no reason to use a level of indirection the vector should store objects not pointers to objects.

I have to admit that I didn't understand your question completely, but this issue needs to be fixed first, because in the presence of undefined behavior the code can do anything or nothing.

Comment: @WillCowan there was no magic involved ;). A container of raw pointers is (almost) always a code smell

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Containers of raw pointers as "internals" according to a sharply dedicated scope are sometimes not avoidable for performance critical tasks. Even unique_ptrs can't always help here in an acceptable way.

Comment: @Secundi thats why I added "(almost)". When they are internals with limited scope they still make me nervous, but I can see easily if they are used right or wrong, actually thats just what happened in this case

Comment: Just wanted to make this clear :) Some users on stackoverflow tend to be resolute for this aspect without having ever developed something in the high performance area...